# quant state for value in PHP array?

Tags: php

i have a code like this:

```
$a = array();
$i = 0;
$a['p'] = !isset($a['p']) ? 0 : $a['p'];
$b = ($i==0 && isset($a['p']) && $a['p'] == 'test') ? 'test' : $i+1;

$i = 1;
$a['p'] = !isset($a['p']) ? 0 : $a['p'];
$c = ($i==0 && isset($a['p']) && $a['p'] == 'test') ? 'test' : $i+1;

echo $a.' '.$b;
```

I`m waiting for 1 in $b, but in fact i have a "test" in $b and 2 in $c
How it is possible ?

PS.
PHP 5.4.16 @ CentOS 7

Comment: cos $a['p'] != 'test' and $a['p'] not a string at all

Comment: it happens because php uses integer comparison, ie `0 == intval('test')`

Comment: `$a['p']` is 0 and when you compare strings and ints some unexpected conversions happen.

Comment: understood, thanks all for answers, in this case we have to use === for comparison